# Bootstrap for phylogenetic tree generated using Mahalanobis distance (R)

Tags: r, tree, statistics-bootstrap, mahalanobis

I created a phylogenetic NJ tree in R using the ape package. My data contains metric measures from multiple individuals belonging to known groups. Thus, I decided to calculate the Mahalanobis distance between these groups in order to incorporate the covariance structure in my analyses. Creating the nj tree thus was not a problem.

```
require(ape)

lda <- lda(y, as.factor(ynames))
dist <- dist(as.matrix(predict(lda,lda$mean)$x),upper=T,diag=T)
plot(nj(dist))
```

However, now I'd like to calculate some bootstrap values for branch splits. I'd use the boot.phylo function, but here I have no idea how I can deal with the FUN (function) command, and thus with the correct calculation of Mahalanobis distances for the bootstrapped data set.

Comment: Checkout this researchgate post about (I think) similar thing. https://www.researchgate.net/post/SOLVED_How_do_you_export_bootstrap_node_support_in_Rs_ape_package

Comment: Thanks, @Amar. However, this doesn't fit my question. I'm not interested in exporting bootstrap values but to generate it.